# Simple way to generate Prime numbers without using set notation

Tags: haskell

I have found multiple ways to generate prime numbers via google, such as those from the wiki: https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers_miscellaneous#One-liners , which often appears in some form like this:

```
sieve (p:px) = p : sieve [n | n <- px, mod n p /= 0]
```

Without using set notation, what is a simple way to generate prime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, just translate the list comprehension notation into its underlying meaning

```
sieve (p:px) = p : sieve (filter (\n -> mod n p /= 0) px)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked without having to change the code structure.

Answer (score 1):

Another inefficient but simple to state expression is

```
nubBy (((==0).).rem) [2..]
```

or with points

```
nubBy (\x y -> x `rem` y == 0) [2..]
```

ps. nubBy is in Data.List

```
> take 100 $ nubBy (\x y -> x `rem` y == 0) [2..]
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,
101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,179,181,191,
193,197,199,211,223,227,229,233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,283,
293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,
409,419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,467,479,487,491,499,503,509,
521,523,541]
```

Comment: why not! It's the same as an inefficient Sieve of Eratosthenes.

Comment: I wonder if I found a bug in GHC because of your post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33531834/nubby-is-not-working-as-expected

Comment: possible!  I think there are backward incompatible changes in 7.10, which I haven't tried yet.