# nubBy is not working as expected

Tags: haskell

The function below should generate prime numbers however it does not for GHC 7.10.2.  Is anybody else seeing this?

```
GHCi, version 7.10.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import Data.List
Prelude Data.List> print . take 100 . nubBy (\x y -> x `rem` y == 0) $ [2..]
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101]
```

The strange part is that it seems to work fine on this site:

[rextester.com/LWZCQ71376](http://rextester.com/LWZCQ71376)

Comment: `nubBy` requires an equivalence relation, I think.

Comment: That's what the docs say and the function passed here is not, which would result in undefined behavior. In practice, it could e.g. have been rewritten in such a way that the arguments are applied in the opposite order (safe for equivalence functions, not for arbitrary functions like this)

Comment: It works here just fine: http://rextester.com/LWZCQ71376

Comment: It works in ghc 7.6.3. Maybe `nubBy` was modified and "optimized" to rely on equivalence relation properties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What changed between base-4.7.x and base-4.8.0.0 is the definition of `elem_by` which is what `nubBy` is defined in terms of.

In base-4.7 `elem_by` has this clause:

```
elem_by eq y (x:xs)     =  y `eq` x || elem_by eq y xs
```

and in base-4.8 it was changed to:

```
elem_by eq y (x:xs)     =  x `eq` y || elem_by eq y xs
```

The history of this change is documented in these TRAC issues:

- [2528](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2528)
- [3280](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3280)
- [7913](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7913)

Note that the Haskell Report Prelude version of `nubBy` is:

```
nubBy eq (x:xs)         =  x : nubBy eq (filter (\ y -> not (eq x y)) xs)
```

which was at odds with the base-4.7 implementation, so that also explains the change.

Comment: The eq function should be commutative, it does seem possible that this change could be the cause of my issue.

Comment: No!! Your `eq` function is NOT commutative!  `rem 4 2 /= rem 2 4`.  One will be equal to zero while the other will be two.

Comment: I think a better term to use is _symmetric_.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I am talking about the change in elem_by. This change should not be a problem for me because if `x \`eq\` y`, then `y \`eq\` x` for all Int.  So this change in elem_by would not be the cause of my issue.

Comment: @ErikR a better term for what?

Comment: @VansonSamuel Are we talking past each other?  In your use, `eq = (\x y -> x \`rem\` y == 0)`.  The change in `elem_by` means for your use to not have an issue the property `(x \`rem\` y == 0) == (y \`rem\` x == 0)` must hold.  I await your proof that such a property holds ;-).

Answer (score 3):

The order of the arguments have been flipped, it seems, in the new base.  EDIT: I called this a bug, but as another answer points out the old behavior was the incorrect order.

You can see the order has been flipped by observing:

```
> print . take 5 . nubBy (\x y -> trace (show (x,y)) $ x `rem` y == 0) $ [2..]
[2(2,3)
,3(3,4)
(2,4)
,4(4,5)
(3,5)
(2,5)
```

Certainly `rem 2 4` does not equal zero (it equals 2), so it yields `4`.

Notice you get the result you desire when you flip the argument order in the lambda:

```
> print . take 5 . nubBy (\x y -> trace (show (x,y)) $ y `rem` x == 0) $ [2..]
[2(2,3)
,3(3,4)
(2,4)
(3,5)
(2,5)
....
```

EDIT: Since discussion indicates the relation is supposed to be equality and operate regardless of the order (and I'm too lazy to look at the report right now) notice you can compare the arguments first and get stable behavior either way:

```
print . take 100 . nubBy (\x y -> rem (max x y) (min x y) == 0) $ [2..]
```

Comment: You'd call this a bug in GHC base?

Comment: Certainly. First, define "bug" as behavior contrary to the Haskell Language specification.  Second, notice this behavior was contrary.  Third, shout "bug".

Comment: `(\x y -> rem (max x y) (min x y) == 0)` might be symmetric, but it is still not an equivalency relation.

Comment: Yes, I was careful to merely call the behavior "stable".